# Where in the world can I fly on a reduced-gravity aircraft as a tourist?

Tags: air-travel, where-on-earth, space

[According to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft):

> A reduced-gravity aircraft is a type of fixed-wing aircraft that provides brief near-weightless environments for training astronauts, conducting research and making gravity-free movie shots.

[image]

<sup>[Image courtesy of NASA](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasafo/8167868818/)</sup>

Where in the world can I take such a flight and what is the *approximate* cost of each operator?

Comment: Nowhere, since a free-fall environment is not zero or  reduced gravity.

Comment: @MartinJames The only time Jonathan Reez used the word "reduced gravity" is in the phrase "reduced gravity aircraft", which is what it's called in Wikipedia.

Comment: @MartinJames since we never know [if we are in zero gravity of if we are free falling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) I think the difference is purely theoretical. If it behaves like zero g, looks like zero g, quacks like zero g, I call it zero g ;)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of 2017, the following companies operate reduced-gravity (aka zero-gravity) flights:

EU:

- [Air Zero G](http://www.airzerog.com), flies from Zurich and Bordeaux. Approximate price: 6000 EUR.

Russia:

- [Gagarin Cosmonaut Training Centre](http://zerogravitytour.com/), near Moscow. Approximate price: 4000 EUR.

United States:

- [Zero Gravity Corporation](http://www.gozerog.com/), scheduled flights from various airports around the US. Approximate price: 4250 EUR.

Comment: Virgin Galactic still hasn't made the list?

Comment: OK Go shot their video for "Upside Down and Inside Out" at the Gagarin facility; the video is enough to make even the most airsickness-prone person want to go do this.  https://www.stereogum.com/1858765/behind-the-scenes-of-ok-gos-zero-gravity-upside-down-inside-out-video/video/

Comment: @Mast Not yet - the implication of the question was "where in the world can I do this *now* "

Comment: @Criggie I understand the question. I'm simply amazed they still haven't done what they went big on all those years ago. That's all.

Comment: @Mast one does not simply walk into space, even if you're Richard Branson.